# Fel:invalid_client when using Google Web application with OAuth 2.0

Tags: web-applications, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I have an issue with the Client ID using from Google API Console with web application.

I first made one to be used with an local application, where the application was getting the redirect url to localhost. And perform the requests to the API in this sense. This worked fine.

But when I'm trying to do the same thing but from a web application using Glassfish and servlet, used the example-code from the link below. I always get a invalid_client when the authorization on google page is triggered. I see that the redirect and have triple check the CLientID and Client Secret, and it is the same as Google API Console state them to be. Even so I always get a invalid_client from Google. (Yes a new Client ID is created for web-application, I'm not using the same as for the application executed at localhost)

http://code.google.com/r/ilyssus-test0/source/browse/?r=40cfcf05804cc7756287605a0cd6a5750a1cdb86#hg%2Fweb-app%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle

Are there any changes that have been forced, that is not included in this example code in the link. Or is there anything I can do to find out what is missing?

I even tried creating different new Client Id for web-applications to see if it was some issue with the one I used. But this was also unsuccessfully.

I also implemented the sample from "DrEdit for Java" on Google Development page, but still get the same result.

Comment: Could you copy paste the URL of the page where you get the error? I'll look into it.

Comment: Also, at what step are you getting the error? is it before or after the authorization grant page? Are you using one of our Client libraries? If yes which one?

Comment: Hello,

Could you tell us what your client id is?

Comment: I found a workaround for the moment, follow the issue here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!starred/oauth2-dev/fLN-D8xrV0w

Comment: Just wanted to let you know we're aware of the issue and working to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a temporary issue with a small set of client ids. The issue should be resolved. If you are still having problems please follow up.